# MySQLdb initial connection timeout

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I'm using `MySQLdb` in python to connect to a remote database and execute a query.  So far so good.  However, it's possible that, for any number of reasons, there simply isn't a MySQL server (or indeed any server) at the designated IP address.  In these cases, at the moment `MySQLdb` hangs indefinitely. This isn't ideal, I'd prefer to be able to set a timeout which if exceeded would allow me to raise and exception and get on with my life.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can pass `connect_timeout` argument to `MySQLdb.connect` function. Quote from [docs](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html):

> connect_timeout
>
> Abort if connect is not completed within given number
>   of seconds.
>
> Default: no timeout (?)